# How to copy zero terminated string including terminating 0 in x86 Assembly (MASM)?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32, irvine32

I'm trying to write a function for copying zero terminated string to another string including terminating 0.

After I call  *stringCopy(str1, str2);* The output should be **Good-bye0ld0** but is **Good-bye** :( what am I missing ?
How to print the correct result?

```
;------------------ in my .cpp file

extern "C" void __stdcall stringCopy(char[], char[]);


int main()
{

    char str1[] = { 'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d',0 };
    cout << str1 << endl;
    char str2[] = { 'G','o','o','d','-','b','y','e',0};
    cout << str2 << endl;

    stringCopy(str1, str2);
    cout << str1 << endl;   ;should be Good-bye0ld0
                            ;but is Good-bye
}


;------------------ in my .asm file
; Copy  zero terminated string2 (including terminating 0)

stringCopy PROC  uses ecx eax esi edi, ;save registers used
                       string1:DWORD,  ;address of string1
                       string2:DWORD   ;address of string2

    cld                                ;forward direction - clear direction flag
    push string2                       ;address of str2 arg to StrlenAsm
    call getStringLength               ;get length of str2
                                       ;called function responsible for stack cleanup
    mov ecx,eax                        ;length of string in ecx for rep
    mov edi,string1                    ;edi gets destination address for copy
    mov esi,string2                    ;esi gets source address for copy
    rep movsb                          ;copy byte from source to desintation ecx times
    mov byte ptr[edi],0                ;null terminate copied string

    ret

stringCopy ENDP


getStringLength PROC uses edi,         ;save edi
           strAdd:DWORD                ;address of string to find length of

    mov edi, strAdd                    ;edi = address of string to get length of
    xor eax,eax                        ;eax to hold length so 0 it out

looptop:
    cmp byte ptr [edi],0               ;have we reached the end of the string yet?
    je done                            ;Yes, done
    inc edi                            ;no, increment to next character
    inc eax                            ;and increment length
    jmp looptop                        ;repeat

done:

ret

getStringLength ENDP
```

Comment: Why not simplify it to a loop that copies and looks for the terminating 0 at the same time?  That's the "normal" way to implement `strcpy(3)`.  Also, doesn't MASM make you fix the stack after a `push`/`call`?  `getStringLength` returns with `ret`, not `ret 4`, so it doesn't pop the operand off the stack.  Anyway, **step through this in a debugger**, and/or look at the disassembly output to see exactly what code the MASM directives produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The output should be **Good-bye0ld0** but is **Good-bye** :( what am I missing ?

IIUC, you are missing the fact that C / C++ string processing functions are stopping at the first encountered null byte (thats why the strings are called "zero-terminated"). Thus after copying the whole `str2` string into `str1`, the standard C++ lib will print the 8 first bytes of it.

> How to print the correct result?

This is the correct result. If you expect to print the null bytes or the number of characters of the initial `str1` content, you can make a loop on the initial length of `str1` to put one character at a time with using `cout << str1[counter]`. You will probably see some smiling or empty characters corresponding to the null bytes.

```
int l = sizeof(str1);
for(int i=0; i<l; i++){
    cout << str1[i];
}
cout << endl;
```